# Is it possible to edit .ePub file via iPad application?

Tags: ipad, pdf, epub

Requirement of the iPad app is to display an `ebook` that allows user to edit and save it. Further requirements are like navigation and bookmarks. In precise, just similar to the **iBooks** app.

My question is, is it possible to edit the `.epub` file? I believe we can edit `.pdf` files (As I have seen some apps available on iTunes). I tried searching on google, all I could find out is, how to display ePub file and how to customize the look of ePub file. Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at

- [**Sigil**](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/)

Since it's open source, you may be able to tweak it to run on IOS.

Wikipedia's [list of ePub editing systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB#Editing_systems) doesn't have an IOS entry yet.

Comment: Seems like nobody implemented Sigil so far.. So I should pick up pdf instead epub??

Comment: @Nina: Well, you initially said 'similar to iBook'. Your named requirements *navigation* and *bookmarks* are fulfilled with PDF. But your requirement *edit and save* is more difficult... Unless your conception of 'edit' is limited to annotation, commenting and highlighting of sections of the file. Then PDF can do that too...

Answer (score 1):

There is an app for editing ePub files, but it's a bit pricey at the moment ($14.99 as of this writing):

- [Easy ePub Creator Pro (link is to the App Store)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-epub-creator-pro/id496165321?mt=8)

There is also a method that uses [GoodReader](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-4/id777310222?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2), but requires several steps to take an ePub file and get it into GoodReader, editable, and then reverse the process after editing.  But GoodReader is cheaper than the above option, and many iPad users already have it for other purposes, so I felt it's worth mentioning.  The following blog post covers it.

- [Editing ePub files entirely on the iPad (blog post at "The Bergen Street Paper Co.")](http://www.bergenstreetpaper.com/2010/12/editing-epub-files-entirely-on-ipad.html)

Also, Kurt's answer points out that [Wikipedia's list of ePub editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB#Editing_systems) doesn't contain an iOS version, but it's worth noting that there are several entries in that list that run on the web.  You might be able to edit your book in Mobile Safari on your iPad.  I haven't tried, but it may be worth investigating.